# Как правильно сделать генерируемые значения по умолчанию для полей в админке Django

Tags: django, django-admin

Нужно сделать три поля. В первых двух генерируется значения по умолчанию (текущее время и его хэш), а третье поле обрезает до 4 знаков и объединяет их как текст в одну строчку.

Я создаю функцию и делаю на неё ссылку из поля модели в default.

```
a = model.CharField(default=function)
```

Соответсвтенно, если перезагрузить страницу с формой, то значения меняются, т.к. текущее время уже другое, это то что надо. Соответсвтенно если делать вызов, то функции то после перезагрузки страницы значения остаются те же, что мне не подходит.

Проблема в том что если не вызывать функцию, а делать ссылкой, то не получается их объеденить на выходе будет

```
a = model.CharField(default=function + function)
```

Это вообще правильно делать в админке Джанго? Потому, что если через свою страницу то понятно дело, что прописал логику в views.py и готово или js на худой конец, но хотелось бы в админке.

Comment: Это лишит вас возможности использовать миграции.

Comment: Вам нужно всегда генерировать новые значения? Даже тогда, когда поле уже имеет значение сохранённое в базе?

Comment: Нет, только на момент заполнения формы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для генерации начальных значений в админке с Django 1.7 есть [специальный метод](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_changeform_initial_data):

```
class SomethingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        return {
            'some_field': some_function(),
        }
```

Для реализации подобного функционала на уровне моделей можно [переопределять метод сохранения](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods):

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    some_filed = model.CharField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.some_filed = some_function()
        super(SomeModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```